# Replacing item databound with jquery ajax calls

Tags: asp.net, jquery, json

We have a very slow ASP.NET page with a repeater. It is slow because most of the processing is done in the ItemDataBound event of the repeater. All this processing just gets 2 totals to be shown in each row.

To increase the throughput, it could be a good idea to load the repeater without ItemDataBound event and without the 2 totals.
Instead on loading the page in browser, AJAX calls can be made from each row and totals can be shown asyncronously.

Can you point to any code example where this kind of solution is achieved.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Indeed the jQuery.ajax() call is a good option here. You can use it to call a [WebMethod](http://encosia.com/2008/05/29/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/) defined in your codebehind

As for the server side calculation, you have a couple options:

1. Embed the values necessary to preform the calculation into HiddenFields within each row and pass them to your webmethod via parameters in the ajax() call.
2. Pass a unique ID for the row using a similar method as above (HiddenField) and do your calculation based on that ID.

As for the code, it could look something like this:

```
$('span.show-total').hover(
    function(){

        // Show panel here

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "PageName.aspx/MethodName",
            data: '{"uniqueId":"' + $(this).find('input[id$=YourHiddenFieldID]').val() + '"}',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(msg) {
                // Do something interesting here.
                alert(msg.d);
            }
        });
    },
    function(){
       // Hide panel here
    }
);
```